# .Net Can't Load Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, .net-core

I added some js files which were exported from Adobe Muse to my wwwroot/js folder. However, when I check the console, it doesn't look like these folders can be found.

I am calling the scripts using:

```
    <script src="~/js/require.js?crc=4157109226" type="text/javascript" async data-main="~/js/museconfig.js?crc=4153641093" onload="if (requirejs) requirejs.onError = function(requireType, requireModule) { if (requireType && requireType.toString && requireType.toString().indexOf && 0 <= requireType.toString().indexOf('#scripterror')) window.Muse.assets.check(); }" onerror="window.Muse.assets.check();"></script>
```

The errors I'm getting are below:

[image]

And finally I have my folders set up as follows

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data-main` attribute is read by `requirejs` and not by `Razor` engine. That is why `requirejs` being a JavaScript library will not be able to resolve `~` in the path. Use `Url.Content` for that, like below.

```
data-main="@Url.Content("~/js/museconfig.js")"
```